# How to show selected option value in drop down value in laravel4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

as i have large numbers of option value(it's about 90) in my form, so i don't store these to seperate table into database for them. the option values are like:

```
<select name="univ" id="univ">
<option value="A University">A University</option>
<option value="B University">B University</option>
<option value="C University">C University</option>
<option value="D University">D University</option>
<option value="E University">E University</option>
<option value="F University">F University</option>
</select>

// Database table
id | .... | univ_name | ....
1  | .... | A University | ....
```

So, the values are saved successfully into the univ column of another table but how to show the selected option value first in the option value by this way?
Is this a good idea to use option value like it? pls help me.

Comment: what is the structure of your stored values? html?

Comment: i have answered your question on laracast forum https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-show-selected-option-value-in-drop-down-value-in-laravel42

Comment: can you explain little more? i don't have separate table for only universities.   @Said Kholov

Comment: What does your option values in the database look like? The same html structure or are they stored as serialized array, comma separated values, json? which one?

Comment: @umefarooq, i am using laravel4.2 and use simple html form and option types....i am a newbie in laravel4.2....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're building your select dynamically since you haven't given very much information.

`$university` being the value in an array. Ie `array('University A')'` and `$univ` being the saved value

```
echo "<option value='{$university}'" . ($univ == $university ? 'selected=\'selected\'': ''). ">{$university}</option>";
```

If not here is how to go about it without using a database to store the university names.

```
$universities = array(
    "A University",
    "B University",
    "C University",
    "D University",
    "E University",
    "F University"
);


echo '<select name="univ" id="univ">';
foreach ($universities as $name) {
    echo "<option value='{$name}' " . ($univ_name == $name ? 'selected=\'selected\'': ''). ">{$name}</option>"; 
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: what is the good way to practice whether keep values into separate table of database or by using the array if this way? @Bankzilla

Comment: where to put this, how to pass this value from controller to view, pls explain little more...i am using laravel 4.2 @Bankzilla

Comment: Sounds like you're in over your head. The `$universities` would go in a database, anything that is data that can be changed, should be stored in a database. In the controller have it as `$this->layout->universities = array(....` This will allow you to use `{{$universities}}` in your view